# Show that function is a test function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, compactness

Consider the domain $D(\mathbb{R})$ of all real test functions. Show that

$f_\epsilon(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
e^{-\frac{c}{\epsilon^2-x^2}} & |x| < \epsilon \\0 & \, |x| \geq \epsilon \\
\end{array}
\right. $

with $c>0$ is in $D(\mathbb{R})$.

My attempt: To show this we need to (1) verify that the function is smooth which is true because it is either an exponential function or $0$? and (2) show that it has a compact support in $\mathbb{R}$.

Well, the function is not equal to $0$ as long as $x \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ and the closure of this interval is $[\epsilon, \epsilon]$ which seems to be compact hence the support is compact.

But I don't think that this is sufficient since there is also the requirement that c has to be postive. How could I show this?

Comment: No, (1) is not so simple. Why are you sure it is continuous at $|x|=\epsilon$? What's the derivative at $|x|=\epsilon$? etc. And $c>0$ is given, you don't have to show it

Answer (score 0):

**Smoothness at the boundary**

The function is smooth on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ because it is an exponential on the interval. The function is smooth on $\mathbb R - [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ because it is the zero outside the interval.

It remains to check smoothness at the points $\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon$. You must show  all the derivatives of $f_\epsilon(x)$ tend to zero at the boundary points. In both directions. This is obvious from the outside directions. From the inside directions you must consider all the derivatives of the exponential function.

Even [the first derivative is nasty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=differentiate+e%5E%28-1%2F%28c%5E2+-x%5E2%29%29) so I imagine there is some trick needed for this problem.